# Should I be using React State for user-interactions (to toggle visibility classes)?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, ref, react-state-management

I am developing a UI library and some of my components change their "state" based upon some interaction from the user.

For example, a user clicks on an accordion panel's title which causes the accordion panel to open and become visible. This state is achieved by adding the `visible` modifier to the accordion panel, like so.:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion_panel-visible">
        <div class="accordion_title">foo</div>
        <div class="accordion_content">bar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_panel">
        <div class="accordion_title">fizz</div>
        <div class="accordion_content">buzz</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My previous assumption was that React State should be used for re-rendering a component based off some back-end data. However, based on looking at the source code from other UI libraries etc, it seems as though they are handling UI states with React State as well.

So using React, I can achieve what I want by using the raw DOM API (as seen by the examples here - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
Accordion.defaultProps = {
    name: 'accordion'
};

class Accordion extends React.Component {
    toggle(event) {
        const panel = event.target.closest('[data-component="panel"]');
        const operator = panel.modifier('active') ? 'unset' : 'set';

        panel.modifier('active', operator); 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Module {...this.props}>
                {this.props.panels.map(({ title, content }, index) => (
                    <Component name='panel' key={index}>
                        <Component name='title' onClick={this.toggle}>{title}</Component>
                        <Component name='content'>{content}</Component>
                    </Component>
                ))}
            </Module>
        )
    }
}
```

which all works great - but I am essentially making DOM manipulations from within a React component, which I constantly read should be avoided. In which case, I should be utilising React State and Refs (instead of direct DOM manipulations). To achieve the same thing as above, I believe I could do:

```
Accordion.defaultProps = {
    name: 'accordion'
};

class Accordion extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.panels = [];
        this.state = { activePanel: null };
    }

    toggle(index) {
        this.setState({ 
            activePanel: (this.panels[index] === this.state.activePanel) ? null : this.panels[index]
        });
    }

    isActive(index) {
        return (this.panels[index] === this.state.activePanel) ? true : false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Module {...this.props}>
                {this.props.panels.map(({ title, content }, index) => (
                    <Component name='panel' 
                        key={index} 
                        ref={ref => this.panels[index] = ref}
                        modifiers={this.isActive(index) ? 'active' : false}
                    >
                        <Component name='title' onClick={this.toggle.bind(this, index)}>
                            {title}
                        </Component>
                        <Component name='content'>{content}</Component>
                    </Component>
                ))}
            </Module>
        )
    }
}
```

(I'm aware the behaviour of the above snippet would close sibling panels, which isn't the case for the first snippet, but this is trivial and can be ignored).

So my question is, should I be utilising React State for this (i.e the latter example)?

It feels like if my app is showing/hiding/opening/closing UI elements based on *user-interactions* which do not require/modify/post/update/get/receive data in any way, then React shouldn't actually care about them.

But most importantly - *is this down to preference* ? Should it be *me* who decides whether or not React should care about this? At the end of the day, react is a tool, a tool which I am currently using to create and render UI components in a back-end free environment. I'm just really confused right now, and not sure I can really see the benefits of using `state` in this context.

Thanks!

Comment: generally direct dom manipulations isn't a great idea if its something that a react component is using unless that item has no correlation to the component (meaning if you just want the value out of something you could grab it via DOM instead of using a ref.. etc). That said usually you would use state when a component needs to toggle some view that is not shared with any other components. if its a variable that is needed for more than one component then you should move it to some store.

Comment: Also, if something is a heavy operation (like `requestAnimationFrame` where you are animating something or rendering a canvas where you draw something on mouse move for example.. that wouldn't need state, you wouldn't need component lifecycle for that just a canvas or direct dom manipulation). so i guess the moral of the story is state is a really useful tool, but situational depending on a usecase. if its a heavy operation you probably can avoid state, if its something that multiple components need then again probably want to use a store. state is good for local manipulations

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell - useful and insightful. It sounds like I *should* be using state for my context. The question still stands as to *why*, though, other than for the sake of it because "it's the proper React way" - of the examples I shared, the React State way requires more code and is less readable, at least to me. But I want to make sure I have the full picture, including things I haven't yet considered.

Comment: Well if you dont use state and mutate the dom directly then whats the point of using react. React no longer knows what is in any element which makes it fairly pointless. You can leverage the power of elements in JS memory. Honestly though I usually avoid state, use redux for my storage and try to have functional components for the rest if possible. State i use for toggling a sidebar in and out and so on

Comment: heres a few links for more reading. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/yes-react-is-taking-over-front-end-development-the-question-is-why-40837af8ab76 ... https://camjackson.net/post/9-things-every-reactjs-beginner-should-know ... https://engineering.opsgenie.com/i-wish-i-knew-these-before-diving-into-react-301e0ee2e488 the first link talks a bit about leveraging the power of html in JS and what you can do with that

Comment: @JohnRuddell In my `app` level (with business logic), I would be using states instead of dom manipulations. It's only in the UI level where I'm considering not using state. For me, being able to write `<Accordion panels={data} /> (as opposed to the entire markup) is a big enough reason alone for me to want to use React, regardless of it I use state or not. Thanks again for your comments and for the further reading material just now!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your concerns, you'd like to put only the backend/communication and business logic to the "React state". But as you pointed out yourself, there is also state related to UI elements. Accordion is closed/opened etc.

One could split this into two categories:

```
   - UI State (only for representation purposes)
   - Business Logic state
```

You can use React's component state for both.

When building or using UI Component libraries the state is often kept/managed within these for sake of encapsulation. For complex applications I'd recommend to use some more powerful state-management like [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux). But there are also cases where people are using react-redux for UI **and** Business Logic state.

From a reusability perspective I'd recommend to have UI Components which are unaware of the actual app use-case (like an Accordion, FancyButton, Snackbar, etc). And another collection of Components which comprise an entire page or pieces of it (Header, Footer, Navigation, MainView, etc).

Then - when going with redux - you can have so called Containers, which wire up the Components with the store/state management of redux.

In any case, using refs for "simple" state modifications should be avoided. Normally this is only required, if you include 3rd party libraries (jQuery like) or [WebComponents/Custom Elements](https://www.webcomponents.org/) since they might not play nicely with React props etc. out of the box.

Regarding the question from the comments: having the task of rendering FrequentlyAskedQuestions (FAQs), the component could look like this:

App related UI component ("stupid"), ./components/FAQ.js:

```
const FAQ = ({faqs}) => (
  <Accordion>
    {faqs.map(faq => (
      <AccordionPane title={faq.title} content={faq.text} />
    ))}
  </Accordion>
)
```

And - using redux - the respective Container, ./containers/FAQ.js:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import FAQ from './FAQ'

const mapStateToProps = state => state.faqs

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FAQ)
```

Comment: Your understanding of my concerns is correct. "You can use React's component state for both." - whilst I certainly *can*, I'm trying to ascertain if I *should*. Having UI components which are unaware of the actual app is precisely my goal - and whilst I am using React to render the raw components, I still feel as though `state` should come into play when the raw component is being *applied* in a meaningful context. So as far as my app is concerned, the `state` might be "learn more accordion is open", but as far as my UI is concerned, why would it also need to know "second panel is open"?

Comment: I see. The Accordion UI Component actually should have an `AccordionContainer`, which does the state handling (only have max. 1 accordion open). So the UI Component are actually two: `<AccordionContainer><Accordion ... /><Accordion .../></AccordionCollection>`. Or as you named them "Accordion" => "AccordionCollection" and "AccordionPanel" => "Accordion".

Comment: In an ideal world, shouldn't the `AccordionContainer` be named something more semantic based off your app and the context it's being used? So maybe `<FrequentlyAskedQuestions><Accordion ... /><Accordion .../></FrequentlyAskedQuestions>`? Apologies if I'm only adding to the confusion here.

Comment: With the API I'm building I'm hoping to do something like `const FAQ = ({faqs}) => (<Accordion panels={faqs} />)` - as far as the app is concerned, it's an FAQ not an accordion, accordion is just how it will be presented (so I could in theory do `const FAQ = ({faqs}) => (<Tabs tabs={faqs} />)`), as such any logic to do with how it is presented I feel should not be exposed to the app, which is why I question my use of *state* in my components. Ultimately, I am building a library which developers will consume, *would it even make a difference to them and their app how I do this*?

Comment: I'm trying to think of what an end user of my library might have to do differently when building their app (if anything) if I choose to handle these interactions *not* using state (the library started off as a general CSS + JS UI library, and I started using React to render the markup, and now basically here I am).

Comment: `const FAQ = ({faqs}) => (<Accordion panels={faqs} />)`, would mean a tight coupling between the faqs object and the panels, which might make the Accordion less generic and reusable. Mapping the faqs to a panels data structure could be done in the `mapStateToProps` of course. Still when designing the Accordion API I'd recommend to keep a second scenario in mind to make it more likely to be reusable.

Comment: Using the React state for managing render state of UI components does not make them less reusable. You are requiring the users already to use React and this comes for free then.

Comment: Actually it's more the other way around - I would like non-react users to still be able to use my UI components (whether just the JS + Sass, or the whole lot), and keeping my interaction logic separate allows me to do this, but if this is at cost to React users, I may reconsider.

Comment: Then you may try to give custom elements (aka WebComponents) a try. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements , which bundle markup, js and css. If you do this vanilla, you can target many different UI libs at zero cost. React does not handle all this too well, but when you know the problems, you can work pretty well with them. List of compatibility: https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely look into WebComponents again. I guess I need to balance the vision I have with the tools people are using.